# Ошибка в Java коде

Tags: java

Как правильно на Java написать эту функцию?

```
int ismiss(int x, int y) { 
  int ans; if
    (mas[x][y]=3) {
      System.out.println("do somth"); 
    }
  return ans; 
}
```

Консоль ругается на строку `(mas[x][y]=3)`.
Полный текст ошибки:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean   table1.java /Ddos/src/main  line 33 Java Problem
```

Comment: попробуй переведи ошибку на русский и поймешь что делать)

Answer (score 3):

```
mas[x][y]=3
```

нужно заменить на

```
mas[x][y]==3
```

Answer (score 0):

Пересмотрите синтаксис языка.
Все дело в том, что выражение mas[x][y]=3 означает , что нужно присвоить значение 3 указанному элементу массива. Вы написали данное выражение в блок if, а последний работает только с типом boolean, отсюда и ошибка. Для сравления элементов нужно использовать == или оператор equals. в данном случае нужно записать mas[x][y]==3, тогда все будет работать. equals используется для ссылочных типов, например, если нужно сравнить строки, но это отдельная история. и еще не ясно, зачем нужна переменная int ans, которую объявили, но ничего с ней не сделали... в данном контексте не исключено, что для того, чтобы вернуть переменную ans, предварительно нужно будет ее явно инициализировать, например , так int ans = 0;